# Is certificate encodedValue needed in WCF client configuration?

Tags: wcf, security

I have WCF service with security mode set to Message:

```
<security mode="Message">
   <message 
      clientCredentialType="UserName" 
      negotiateServiceCredential="true" 
      establishSecurityContext="true" 
      algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
...
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
      ...
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="my Certifiacate ..."/>
      </serviceCredentials>
```

and service certificate is given in serviceBehaviors section.

When VS creates client (.NET) (by Add service reference) it creates `<identity><certificate encodedValue="long string"/></identity>` element in web.config.

I found that client can connect service successfully even when this section is blank. My guess is that client uses encoded value of service certificate to encrypt the message. But when encoded value is not specified in configuration it also works? So what is purpose of that?

Comment: weird is all I have to say our services with config like in my answer fail epically when the server cert is missing.

Comment: @the_ajp you misread my question. I am talking that it works when client config section is blank

Comment: I meant to say our clients with a missing server cert config will fail.

Comment: has you got negotiateServiceCredential="true" ? my guess it makes the difference

Comment: that does take care of the server certificate getting sent to the client absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

It only encrypts when you've specified in your wcf config that you want to use encryption in your binding.

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding>
    <security mode="Message">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
       algorithmSuite="TripleDesSha256Rsa15" establishSecurityContext="true" />
     </security>
   </binding>
</wsHttpBindings>
```